# I can't draw green square in lwjgl

Tags: java, colors, lwjgl

This probably sounds weird, but somehow my program just ignores green color

First, I init GL like this: (I don't know, maybe it does matter)

```
private static void initgl() {
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 1280, 720, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

I'm drawing a square like this:

```
public static void gameLoop(){
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()){
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        DrawStuff.square(10, 10, 100, 100, new byte[]{127,127,127});
        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }
}
```

and in square method I have

```
public static void square(int x, int y, int w, int h, byte[] rgb) {
    glColor3b(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2i(x, y);
    glVertex2i(x + w, y);
    glVertex2i(x + w, y + h);
    glVertex2i(x,y+h);
    glEnd();

}
```

When I run the program, I see this:

[image]

And by the way, color picker says it's #C808C7 . Not even #FF00FF like I expected

1. what happened to the green color?
2. why colors are off?

Comment: Output the 'rgb[0-2]' in the 'square' method and tell us the output please.

Comment: @Reaper `System.out.println(rgb[0]);` (for all three 0-2) -- says `127`

Comment: weird... That means it should be a dark gray.  I haven't used LWJGL in a while so I don't think I can help you out. Sorry.

Comment: @Reaper Here bytes are signed, so from -128 to 127. It's white :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this answer helped me: [How do color and textures work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134353/how-do-color-and-textures-work-together)

> That's not your problem, but it still needs to be done.

What was messing with my colors is `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` To achieve both color and texture filling I have to disable it each time I want to draw something with solid color and then enable again:

```
public static void square(int x, int y, int w, int h, byte[] rgb) {
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glColor3b(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2i(x, y);
    glVertex2i(x + w, y);
    glVertex2i(x + w, y + h);
    glVertex2i(x,y+h);
    glEnd();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

}
```

Depending on your case, future reader, you may want to keep it disabled in the first place, only enabling it if you need to add textures.

Volia: [image]